# std::dynarray vs std::vector

Tags: c++, stdvector

C++14 presents [`std::dynarray`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/dynarray):

> std::dynarray is a sequence container that encapsulates arrays with a
>   size that is fixed at construction and does not change throughout the
>   lifetime of the object.

`std::dynarray` must be allocated in run-time as same as `std::vector`.

So what are the benefits and the usage of `std::dynarray` while we can use `std::vector` which is more dynamic (and also re-sizable)?

Comment: Hey, since when is "C++14" a tag? I was looking for that the other day and it didn't exist...

Comment: Is `std::valarray` renamed as `std::dynarray`? Whats dynamic about `std::dynarray` when it cannot be re-sized?

Comment: @yasouser, no, it's nothing to do with `valarray`. It's dynamic because the length of the array is a run-time value, it doesn't need to be known at compile-time, unlike `std::array`

Comment: Edited tag to C++1y as that is the used tag over SO until the standard is actually there.

Comment: Note that at the C++ Standards Committee meeting last week, `dynarray` was removed from C++14 and put into a future Technical Specification (think of that as a new version of TR1) because it has some serious technical problems.

Comment: @PeteBecker: Great to hear that, as the current version of `dynarray` seems to be a bad idea…

Comment: @MFH: Why do you think it's a bad idea?

Comment: @MM.: first of all: there currently seems to be no implementation - which is an extremely bad sign and the standards committee learned the hard way not to specify features that are not well tested (e.g. export, dynamic exception specification,…) second: the fact that `dynarray` allocates on the stack leads to several potential new pitfalls (e.g. running out of stack space) all leading to undefined behavior and in addition to that prevents optimizations like move semantics… To me this seems like a hidden behind a STL-like layer VLA, which was not adopted in C++ for good reasons.

Comment: Was `dynarray` _required_ to be able to use stack allocation since its first proposal, or was it something added afterwards? As soon as I heard about the concept of a dynarray I started using a trivial implementation (one of those "why didn't C++ already have this?" cases) but this is the first I hear it was required to be able to do allocation by means beyond just calling `operator new` (that simplicity was one of the strongest points IMO).

Comment: @LuisMachuca: Very, very, very late reply: `dynarray` was expected to do stack-allocation whenever possible (if supported by the compiler + library) and use heap allocation (`new[]`) only as fallback if that was not possible… (e.g. when not supported or not applicable)

Comment: [dynarray](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/dynarray) is no longer a part of the draft C++14

Comment: @deepmax I suggest you to remove the C++14 tag and edit your question according to the fact that dynarray is **NOT** part of C++14.

Comment: You can put dynarray and std::vector in context of each other, and other array/vector-like types, using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67409339/1593077).

Answer (score 100, accepted):

> So what are the benefits and the usage of `std::dynarray`, when we can use `std::vector` which is more dynamic (Re-sizable)?

`dynarray` is smaller and simpler than `vector`, because it doesn't need to manage separate size and capacity values, and it doesn't need to store an allocator.

However the main performance benefit is intended to come from the fact that implementations are encouraged to allocate `dynarray` on the stack when possible, avoiding any heap allocation. e.g.

```
std::dynarray<int> d(5);   // can use stack memory for elements
auto p = new std::dynarray<int>(6);  // must use heap memory for elements
```

This optimisation requires cooperation from the compiler, it can't be implemented as a pure library type, and the necessary compiler magic has not been implemented and noone is sure how easy it is to do. Because of the lack  of implementation experience, at the C++ committee meeting in Chicago last week it was decided to pull `std::dynarray` from C++14 and to issue a separate array extensions TS (technical specification) document defining `std::experimental::dynarray` and arrays of runtime bound (ARBs, similar to C99 VLAs.)  This means `std::dynarray` will almost certainly not be in C++14.

Comment: Great, I was wondering if there were *any* non-trivial implementations of `dynarray` in the wild. I always thought you need two independent implementations of existing practice before something becomes eligible for standardization.

Comment: No, there are no known implementations of a stack-allocating `dynarray`. Although implementation experience is very useful, there is no set rule requiring it (but some would say there should be!)

Comment: just brainstorming here but what about creating 2 functions: std::dynarray make_dyn_autostorage(int) and std::dynarray make_dyn_heap(int)?

Comment: @ServéLaurijssen: I think once you return such an object from a function, you don't have a choice about the implementation anymore. At best the compiler can detect when you're using a dynamic array in a purely local setting and with small enough size to fit it on the stack.

Comment: @ServéLaurijssen, that doesn't help: how do you make a `std::dynarray` allocate on the stack? Who reserves the stack space? You still need compiler magic.

Comment: Hang on, are you saying that ARBs are also not going to be in the next standard?

Comment: @KerrekSB, yes, library motion 10 in Chicago was: "Move we create a Working Paper for a planned Array Extensions TS, remove the edits applied to the C++14 CD by the two papers [N3639](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3639.html), "Runtime-sized arrays with automatic storage duration (revision 5)" [N3662](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3662.html), "C++ Dynamic Arrays (dynarray)" and direct the Array Extensions TS project editor to apply those words to the Array Extensions Working Paper as its initial content."

Comment: There were some strong feelings that the two proposals are coupled and should not be standardised separately, and also improving the ARB feature might make it easier to implement `dynarray`

Comment: I don't understand why a stack allocator wouldn't perform well instead of std::dynarray full implementation, modulo the state that must be kept. Why a compiler needs optimizations here?

Comment: I love the way the C++ guys name they spec: Technical Report 1; Technical Specification ... Sounds both primitive and advanced.

Comment: @h9uest that is nothing to do with "the C++ guys", those are the official names for the deliverables of an [ISO](http://www.iso.org/) technical committee, see http://www.iso.org/iso/home/standards_development/deliverables-all.htm?type=ts and http://www.iso.org/iso/home/standards_development/deliverables-all.htm?type=tr

Comment: There is this header-only VLA library from year 2021 working with C++17: https://github.com/cnbatch/dynarray

Comment: That doesn't have the interesting properties of `dynarray`

Answer (score 31):

As you said yourself, `std::dynarray` is for a *fixed-size* dynamic array. It is not resizable. It's roughly speaking an improvement over `new T[N]` and over `std::unique_ptr<T[]>(new T[N])`.

Not needing to resize or manage capacity means you can implement the data structure with less complexity and in less space.

Moreover, `std::dynarray` is a weird animal that allows the implementation to implement it in different, non-specific ways, e.g. it's possible to put the array on the stack. Calling an allocation function is "optional". You can specify an allocator to construct the elements of the array, but that is not part of the type.

You might also wonder why we need `std::dynarray` *and* variable-length arrays. VLAs in C++14 are much more restrictive; they can only be local, automatic variables and offer no way to specify an allocation policy, and of course they don't have a standard container interface.

---

Some examples from 23.3.4.2 of a "current draft" (take that, Google cache):

> ```
> explicit dynarray(size_type c);
> ```
>
> *Effects:* Allocates storage for `c` elements. **May or may not invoke the global `operator new`.**

> ```
> template <class Alloc>
> dynarray(size_type c, const Alloc& alloc);
> ```
>
> *Effects:* Equivalent to the preceding constructors except that **each element is constructed with uses-allocator construction**.

Whether or not you *can* use a given allocator to construct the array elements is a global trait:

> template 
>      struct uses_allocator, Alloc> : true_type { };
>
> *Requires:* `Alloc` shall be an Allocator (17.6.3.5). [*Note:* Specialization of this trait informs other library components that `dynarray` can be constructed with an allocator, even though it does not have a nested allocator_type.]

**Edit:** Jonathan Wakely's answer is bound to be far more authoritative and insightful.

Comment: Passing an allocator to `dynarray`'s constructor is never used for allocation, it's only used as an argument to the elements' constructors (using "uses-allocator construction"). That's why you can't query if the allocator was used: because it never is.