# Are there plans to implement std::dynarray in next C++ standard?

Tags: c++, dynarray

I read that std::dynarray was proposed in a draft for C++14 but was dropped out later on.

Are there any plans that this class will be included in future C++ standards, or has it been dropped for good?

Comment: `dynarray` was part of a draft experimental Technical Specification (n3820) concerned with array extensions.  The last version of that draft was dated 10 October 2013, and subsequent development was abandoned.   As far as I know, there has been no subsequent development of any similar proposal.

Comment: Related: [std::dynarray vs std::vector](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19111606/430766)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No plans so far. The latest info is from this 2017 paper: https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/p0785r0.html

A custom header-only implementation from 2021 can be found here: https://github.com/cnbatch/dynarray

And good discussions: [Why aren't variable-length arrays part of the C++ standard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1887097/why-arent-variable-length-arrays-part-of-the-c-standard/21519062#21519062)
https://stackoverflow.com/a/1887178/7471760